# Slicing based on a range of column in a multiindex column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, multi-index

I am creating my dataframe by doing the following:

```
months        = [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ]
monthyAmounts = [ "actual", "budgeted", "difference" ]

income = []
names  = []

for x in range( incomeIndex + 1, expensesIndex ):
    amounts = [ randint( -1000, 15000 ) for x in range( 0, len( months ) * len( monthyAmounts ) ) ]
    income.append( amounts )
    names.append( f"name_{x}" )

index    = pd.Index( names, name = 'category' )
columns  = pd.MultiIndex.from_product( [ months, monthyAmounts ], names = [ 'month', 'type' ] )
incomeDF = pd.DataFrame( income, index = index, columns = columns )
```

The dataframe looks like:
(removed months March - December)

```
          Jan                            Feb                        ...             
          actual   budgeted   difference actual budgeted difference
name_13   14593     -260      10165      9767     629    10054
name_14    6178     1398      13620      1821   10986     -663
name_15    2432     3279       7545      8196    1052     7386
name_16    9964    13098      10342      5564    4631     7422
```

What I want is for every row, to slice the difference column for the months Jan - May. What I can do it slice the difference column for all of the months by doing:

```
incomeDifferenceDF = incomeDF.loc[ :, idx[ :, 'difference' ] ]
```

which gives me a dataframe that looks like:
(months March - December removed)

```
         Jan        Feb          ....
         difference difference                         
name_13       10165      10054  
name_14       13620       -663  
name_15        7545       7386  
name_16       10342       7422
```

What I have tried is:

```
incomeDifferenceDF = incomeDF.loc[ :, idx[ 'Jan' : 'May', 'difference' ] ]
```

but that gives me the error:

```
UnsortedIndexError: 'MultiIndex slicing requires the index to be lexsorted: slicing on levels [0], lexsort depth 0'
```

So, this seems close, but I am uncertain how to resolve the problem.

I have also tried:

```
incomeDifferenceDF = incomeDF.loc[ :, idx[ ['Jan':'May'], 'difference' ] ]
```

But that just generates the error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
( Points at ['Jan':'May'] )
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need select by `MultiIndex`, need boolean masks:

```
index    = pd.Index( [1,2,3,4], name = 'category' )
budgetMonths = pd.date_range( "January, 2018", periods = 12, freq = 'BM' ) 
months        = [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
                  'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ]
monthyAmounts = [ "actual", "budgeted", "difference" ]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product( [ months, monthyAmounts ], names = [ 'month', 'type' ])
incomeDF = pd.DataFrame( 10, index = index, columns = columns )

#trick for get values between 
idx = pd.Series(0,index=months).loc['Jan' : 'May'].index
print (idx)
Index(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'], dtype='object')

mask1 = incomeDF.columns.get_level_values(0).isin(idx)
mask2 = incomeDF.columns.get_level_values(1) == 'difference'

incomeDifferenceDF = incomeDF.loc[:, mask1 & mask2]
print (incomeDifferenceDF)
month           Jan        Feb        Mar        Apr        May
type     difference difference difference difference difference
category                                                       
1                10         10         10         10         10
2                10         10         10         10         10
3                10         10         10         10         10
4                10         10         10         10         10
```

Comment: hmmm, `1-01-01` is not valid date, but need test this. Give me some time.

Comment: Take all the time you need...thank you...however, perhaps, the timeseries and slicing using the specific dates is good enough...but, it would still be nice to be able to slice based on Month name ( ex. 'Jan' : 'May' )

Comment: @ericg - If values are sorted like in your new sample, your solution working nice.

Comment: @ericg - hmmm, if want use names of months, it is problem for selecting, because is not possible sorting. So possible solution should be change month names to numbers.

Comment: @ericg - One possible solution was added, but complicated - need boolean masks.

Comment: Ya, I think you've convinced me that trying to slice on month names is not the right way to go about it. If you can remove the two lines after "I think need:" which generate an error, I will mark this as the answer.